# What is the STD of the distribution of categorical data?

Tags: python, statistics, categorical-data, standard-deviation

K-Means clustering allows one to look for centroids in a multivariate dataset. The outputs are those centroids as well as 'labels' which is essentially a list of integers between 1 and k representing at each time step, what is the closest centroid to the empirical ndarray. 
I am looking at the distribution of those and want to compute the standard deviation for determining error bars in a bar plot. 
I have tried to consider a boolean equivalent of that 'labels' array for each possible value (labels==1, labels==2 etc.) to be able to apply the Binomial formula of the STD (P(1-P)/N)^0.5 but I don't think that's quite right..? Also, values I get are quite small, around 10^-3 which leads me to believe I'm not using the good formula or not assuming the right things... 
Any guess how I could compute the standard deviation of the distribution of categorical data? 
Thanks in advance!